# get content loaded with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Installed an app for shopify (qucik view) which shows product in a popup. It looks like all of the content and data is loaded into divs with specific id's an classes with json. I'm trying to pull and edit some parts of it (like hrefs) with jquery, but have no luck. I'm new to js, so it look like there is something i don't know.

Trying to make it with standard jquery lines

```
$(".sca-qv-showqv").each(function(){
   var ttlhref = $(this).find("#sca-qv-detail").attr("href");
   $(this).find("a.sca-qv-title").attr("href",ttlhref);
});
```

My guess is that it's trying to pull data before all of it is loaded. I've also tried window load, and no luck with that. Errors from console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .main-nav ul li ul. .superimage img
sca-qv-pro-scripts-noconfig.js?shop=mineral-fusion.myshopify.com:4 load jquery 1.11
jquery.js:9592 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
sca-qv-pro-scripts-noconfig.js?shop=mineral-fusion.myshopify.com:3 collection_handle : undefined
sca-qv-pro-scripts-noconfig.js?shop=mineral-fusion.myshopify.com:3 Disable QV : 
sca-qv-pro-scripts-noconfig.js?shop=mineral-fusion.myshopify.com:3 image_zoom_type : original
sca-qv-pro-scripts-noconfig.js?shop=mineral-fusion.myshopify.com:3 image_show_type : large
foundation.min.map:1 GET http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0519/3185/t/10/assets/foundation.min.map 404 (Not Found)
app.css.map:1 GET http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0519/3185/t/10/assets/app.css.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Could you post the html code generated by the app?

Comment: it doesn't really generate much code. For the most part, it's just adding attribute values and plain text to divs and a's according to their id's and classes.

Comment: What is the problem you are running into? Post any error that you see in console or anywhere.

Comment: baiscally, my script doesn't pull any data. there are no related errors in the console, but i've updated code and added errors

Comment: The `ul.` is not a valid selector, because class names can't be empty.

Comment: that ul relates to something different, it's a hack and it works